# Send HTTP request when user confirm Abort in Inno

Tags: inno-setup

I wish to send Http request when the user abort the setup 
how can I address the abort message box that pops up after the user clicks Cancel button?
I wish to send the Http request when the user click "Yes" on the message box.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event function CancelButtonClick to know find out what the user clicked and send the actual HTTP in this function or in DeinitializeSetup function. Note that the HTTP request might take time so the user might see the installer gui "freezing" for some time. You may want to do the HTTP in another thread (for example using dll)
The function reference is in [Event Functions](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptpages)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way!
  here -

```
procedure CancelButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer; var Cancel, Confirm: Boolean);
begin
   Cancel := False;
  if ExitSetupMsgBox = True then 
  begin
        Cancel := True;
        Confirm := False;
        WinHttpReq := CreateOleObject('WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1');
        WinHttpReq.Send();  

  end;
```